# Best way to store data from excel sheet for automation framework

Tags: java, excel, selenium

I am creating automation framework using JAVA and using test data source as excel sheet.Currently extracting all data from excel sheet into LinkedHashmap and using linkedhashmap in code. My question is to know efficient way of extracting data from excelsheet.
My HashMap looks like

```
public static HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> exceldata = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>();
```

Row number and data for that row.
I am using apache POI to get data from excel sheet.However i have to store it in data structure to do some metadata.

```
File fs=new File(AppVariableConstants.TestDataPath);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fs);
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook (fis);
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            int rows; // No of rows
            int cols;
            String KeyHeader;
            String ValueCell=null;
            rows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
            cols=sheet.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
            public static HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> exceldata = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>();      
            for(int i=1; i<rows; i++){
                ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                for(int j=0; j<cols ;j++) {
                     KeyHeader=sheet.getRow(0).getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
                     switch(sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j).getCellType()) {
                 case NUMERIC:
                     ValueCell=String.valueOf(sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j).getNumericCellValue());
                     break;
                     exceldata.put(i, list1);// row number and all data for that row
```

Comment: Try using one of the open source libraries like Apache POI. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: i am using apache POi to read data i just want to save it in data structure for further use.

Comment: HashMap looks good to start with but it really depends upon how you are going to use the data.

Answer (score 0):

for the best performance you should use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) replace your HashMap

Using `Workbook` interface for read and write your sheet, cell, row, etc...